# Compound if / logical XOR bash bug?

Tags: bash, xor, logical-operators

```
#!/bin/bash

function logic_test()
{
    left_bracket=$1
    right_bracket=$2

    if [[ ($left_bracket || $right_bracket) && ! ($left_bracket && $right_bracket) ]]
    then
        errEcho "Input error: insertIntoConfigFile arg1 does not contain matching []."
    else
        errEcho "Passed"
    fi
}

logic_test true true
logic_test true false
logic_test false true
logic_test false false
```

Expected results, as per XOR's functioning:

```
Passed
Input Error
Input Error
Passed
```

Actual results in 4.3.11(1)-release

```
Passed
Passed
Passed
Passed
```

Am I failing to see something trivial in my XOR implementation, or is the if logic buggy? If it is a bug, how do I go about submitting said bug?

I'm thinking this might be a bug...if I change the if to

```
if [[ ($left_bracket && !$right_bracket) || (!$left_bracket && $right_bracket) ]]
```

then all 4 outputs become "input error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set -xv` to turn on debugging. It will show you the problem: bash interprets the things in `[[ .. ]]` as strings and tests them with `-n`. None of them is emtpy, so it works as 'true true' everytime.

To fix it, just remove the `[[` and `]]`. Bash will correctly interpret `true` and `false` as commands to run and use their exit code in the logic.

Comment: I can't mark this as an answer for another 4 minutes, but spot on. I had no idea I could have an if statement *without* the [[ ]]. Interesting.